# jQuery hover: does not work for each instance of ".map"

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So in my index view i have this (shortened to show the important part)

```
<% @tutor.map do |tutor| %>
  <%= image_tag(asset_url('question-mark.png'), class: 'hoverIcon', size:'16x16') %>
  <div id='hoverRating' style='display: none;'>
    <p>
      The Rating is ... 
    </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here's the script

```
$('.hoverIcon').hover(
  function () {
    $('#hoverRating').show();
  },
  function () {
    $('#hoverRating').hide();
  }
);
```

So the problem i have is that on the first instance of the image, the `hover` function works perfectly fine, but when i go onto the second instance of the image and i `hover` over it, the `#hoverRating` appears over the first instance of the image instead.

How do i make it such that for each instance of the image, the `#hoverRating` that appears is over that particular image that is being hovered over instead?

Answer (score 2):

*Identifiers in HTML must be unique.*, You can assign a common class i.e `hoverRating`, then `.find()`/`.children()` to target the element.

*Code*

```
<% @tutor.map do |tutor| %>
  <%= image_tag(asset_url('question-mark.png'), class: 'hoverIcon', size:'16x16') %>
  <div class='hoverRating' style='display: none;'>
    <p>
      The Rating is ... 
    </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*Script*

```
$('.hoverIcon').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('.hoverRating').show();
  },
  function () {
    $(this).find('.hoverRating').hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: That makes them all appear together at the same time. What if i want them to show up individually?

Comment: @angkiki you have to organize your html in a way that the image you're hovering over has access to the `.hoverRating` element you want to show. One way is to add an identifier to each element, how do you do that ?, one way is this: add to your `image_tag` line a data attribute like this `data-tutor-id: #{tutor.id}`, and in your `hoverRating` append the id of the tutor to the class attribute: `<div class='hoverRating tutor-id-#{tutor-id}'>`. And in your jquery code, change to something like: `$(this).find('.hoverRating tutor-id-' + $(this).data('tutor-id')).show();`. Give it a try.

Comment: another way is moving all that html(the one inside your `map` block) in another div, lets say: `<div class='rating-wrapper'> <%= image_tag...>...</div>`. And then, in your jquery, find the parent of `this` and then the `hoverRating` element: `$(this).parent().find('.hoverRating').show()`. This way the javascript will find only one element because you're looking inside a parent div, and each `hoverRating` element is inside its own div.

Comment: @fanta i went with your second solution and it works perfectly. if you would like you may submit it as an answer and i would mark it as correct. thank you!

Comment: @fanta you should sumbit it as an answer